# C++ constructor with static array

Tags: c++, constructor

Trying to learn C++ and hitting a wall with a few things.  Would appreciate some pointers from the C++ experts on explaining on what is happen ing under the hood.

My `BigNum` class is below.  My questions are

1. `BigNum b1 = BigNum(2, {2, 8});` does not work `Error:  No matching constructor for initialization of 'BigNum'`

   - But `int arr[] = {2, 8}; BigNum b1 = BigNum(2, arr);` works
2. I also see some compiler warnings for all constructors below. E.g:`Candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided` for the default  constructor below
3. Is there a one-line way to initialize the private members in the constructor. E.g:

   - `BigNum(int numDigits, int digits[]): _n(numDigits), _digits(digits) {};`
   - Or even better  `BigNum(int numDigits = 0, int digits[] = {}): _n(numDigits), _digits(digits) {};`

```
class BigNum {
    int _n = 0;
  int _digits[MAX_DIGITS] = {};
public:
  BigNum() {};
  BigNum(int numDigits, int digits[]) {
    if (numDigits >= MAX_DIGITS || numDigits < 0) {
      return;
    }
    _n = numDigits;
    memcpy(_digits, digits, _n * sizeof(_digits[0]));
  };
  BigNum(const BigNum &bigNum) {
    _n = bigNum._n;
    memcpy(_digits, bigNum._digits, _n * sizeof(_digits[0]));
  };
};
```

Comment: **1.** You likely want a constructor taking [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). With such a constructor, you could do `BigNum({2, 8})` **2.** Those are not separate warnings, but further explanations for the original error. The compiler tells you what constructors it tried, and why each one was found unsuitable.

Comment: **3.** There would be if you use something better than a plain C array for storing your digits - e.g. `std::array` or `std::vector`. These can be initialized in the constructor initializer list, while plain array cannot.

Comment: Thanks does the ```std::initializer_list``` work if data member is an `int array`.  Seems to only work for ```std::vector```

Comment: Just saw your comment for 3.  Thanks.  yes using ```std::initializer_list``` for the param and using for loop to initialize _digits works.

Can you make this the answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: You might find "BigNum() = delete;" useful.

Answer (score 3):

So, to echo what Igor said in the comments, `std::vector` has a convenient constructor from an `initializer_list`, so you could do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

class BigNum {
    std::vector <int> digits;
public:
    BigNum (int max_digits) : digits (max_digits) {}
    BigNum (std::initializer_list <int> initial_digits) : digits (initial_digits) {}
};

int main()
{
    BigNum bn ( { 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
    BigNum bn2 (5);
}
```

Note that we now don't need a copy constructor - the default one generated by the compiler will work just fine.